# Зачем в getInstance synchronized?

Tags: android, synchronized

Зачем в этом getInstance synchronized делать ?

Это класс-синглтон для работы с сетью с использованием retrofit.

```
public static NetworkWorker getInstance(){
    if (networkWorker == null){
        synchronized (NetworkWorker.class) {
            if (networkWorker == null) {
                networkWorker = new NetworkWorker();
            }
        }
    }
    return networkWorker;
}
```

Comment: Зачем в этом примере две проверки на null?

Comment: ну наверно же что бы не появилось два экземпляра NetworkWorker...разве это не следует из применяемого паттерна

Comment: @Werder я не знаю. писал не я) увидел пример - хочу узнать почему так.

Comment: @ermak0ff я никогда не юзал синхронайзд.. и плохо понимаю как он работает. ну а зачем он в синглтоне - хз. може же писать if(worker==null){create worker;} or return worker; поправьте если ошибаюсь. спасибо!

Comment: Хорошая статья по теме - https://habrahabr.ru/post/27108/. В конце статьи написано как написать синхронизированный синглтон

Comment: @Werder двойная проверка необходима что бы не делать весь метод synchronized

Comment: researcher  для того что бы корректно работать в многопоточной среде

Comment: @ermak0ff, т.е. всегда при использование синглтона надо делать синхронайзд ?

Comment: @ermak0ff, да, спасибо, совершенно верно

Comment: researcher если для вас слово поток звучит непривычно и пугающе, то можете не делать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При реализации синглтона даже с synchronized бывают случаи, когда при использовании многопоточности потокам удается дважды создать инстанс одного класса - что для реализации паттерна неприемлемо.

Synchronized нужен, для того, что-бы в методе\объекте в данный момент мог работать лишь один поток, и остальные ожидали окончания работы. По сути это очередь.

Если-бы это был просто класс, который необходимо защитить экраном synchronized -  то проверка на null была бы одна, но поскольку здесь происходит реализация синглтона -  то и проверки нужно сделать две.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: Тут еще нужно использование локальной переменной, чтобы уж совсем все предусмотреть. И монитором, а не экраном.

Comment: @DanielOlivo а можно поподробнее о локальной переменной?

Comment: @researcher вот скрин http://joxi.ru/ZrJdXX7h1PEKd2 с псевдокодом. Локальная переменная для того, чтобы предотвратить создание инстанса в момент между услвоием и синхронизацией в другом потоке. В таком случае может возникнуть ситуация, при которой два потока валидно получают два разных инстанса, не смотря на монитор.

Answer (score 3):

Паттерн называется Double checked locking. Призван в случае ленивой инициализации ликвидировать дорогую синхронизацию (в случае когда getInstance объявляется синхронным), которая нужна **только** когда несколько потоков обращаются за инстансом в момент его инициализации, при последующих обращениях синхронизация не нужна.

У правильной реализации данного паттерна полно проблем: и happens before (когда ссылка на объект доступна вне критической секции до окончания инициализации) и деградация производительности из-за volatile...

Если ситуация позволяет, то синглтон правильнее создавать сразу при объявлении. Либо гарантировать запуск потоков строго после инициализации синглтона, при этом DCL использовать ни к чему.

Comment: Я рассматривал код класса, через который делаются разнообразные запросы к серверу и там есть этот кусок кода. Перечитаю Ваш ответ и попробую разобраться как правильно реализовать синглтон для такого класса. Спасибо!